# Bug or feature? Weird indentation breaks ruby hashes declaration

Tags: ruby, indentation

I quite like this indentation style:

```
hash = 
  [ "bla" => :bla
  , "bli" => :bli
  , "blo" => :blo
  ]
```

but Ruby does not like that so much.

This is OK:

```
{ 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2 }
#=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2}
```

But this:

```
{ 'a' => 1
, 'b' => 2 }
```

yields

```
-:2: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '}'
, 'b' => 2 }
 ^
-:2: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting end-of-input
, 'b' => 2 }
        ^
```

Is intended by the author or is it a weird bug?

Comment: What is `<<<` ? `ruby <<< "{ 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2 }" #=> syntax error, unexpected '<'`. Change `<<<` to `<<` and an "undefined method or local variable" exception is raised.

Comment: An attempt to produce a heredoc. @￼変幻出没: `\n` is not escaped properly, try `cat <<< "{ 'a' => 1\n, 'b' => 2 }"`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Basically tells `a <<< "b"` tells `a` to consider `b` as `stdin`.  Here you can just replace it by `-e`. For more information see bash manual at section "Here Strings" (The word undergoes brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal.  Pathname expansion and word splitting are not performed.  The result is supplied as a single string to the command on its standard input.)

Comment: @Koterpillar What does you mean by not correctly escaped? In all cases, even replacing `<<<` to `-e` gives the same error. And placing it in a separate text file is the same.

Comment: @変幻出没 `\n` appears in the temporary file as two characters, not as a line break. However, yes, it seems that a) end of line is significant in Ruby b) errors on parsing this file are misleading.

Comment: Why should I consult the bash manual for an explanation of Ruby syntax? You are not executing a shell command from within Ruby. See, for example, [this](http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html).

Comment: Only because `<<<` is bash syntax. But you can safely ignore it and replace it by "-e". I did not mean any offence.

Comment: @変幻出没 Your code passes a literal `\n` to ruby. To generate a newline character, you have to use something like `ruby <<< $'{ \'a\' => 1\n, \'b\' => 2 }'` or `echo -e "{ 'a' => 1\n, 'b' => 2 }" | ruby`. This will still result in a syntax error, but the correct one.

Comment: @変幻出没 I've removed the bash part.

Comment: @Stefan Thank you, that's indeed better this way since it won't lead to other weird issues due to my rusty bash skills.

Comment: To downvoters, I don't mind being downvoted, but at least explain why you do so, so I can improve this post or to the least take your remarks into account for my future posts.

Comment: Requests for explanations from downvoters are never answered (sadly). I was initially confused by your reference to bash. You edited that out, but that caused another problem: it made several of the comments nonsensical. When editing you should have left what you had and added to it, clearly indicating it was an edit (e.g. "Edit: ..."). (Had your edit not conflicted with comments or answers it would have been OK.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a `\` to each line:

```
hash = 
  [ "bla" => :bla \
  , "bli" => :bli \
  , "blo" => :blo \
  ]
#=> [{"bla"=>:bla, "bli"=>:bli, "blo"=>:blo}]
```

Comment: Ok, but that's more or less the same problem, replacing `,` by `\`, but it clearly means that like @Koterpillar said endline in Ruby are significant.

Comment: Yes, apparently the parser expects a trailing comma. This is merely a "hack" to join the lines while sill having a leading comma in your editor.

Answer (score 1):

Just move the commas before the line breaks, and ruby is happy again:

```
hash = 
  [ "bla" => :bla,
    "bli" => :bli,
    "blo" => :blo
  ]

#=> [{"bla"=>:bla, "bli"=>:bli, "blo"=>:blo}]
```

Comment: Thank you for stating the obvious, I was just reporting (what I thought) a strange behaviour of Ruby.

Comment: @変幻出没 The reason for what you see as strange behaviour is that Ruby doesn't require semicolons. Expressions may be separated by either semicolons or linebreaks. Thus, linebreaks are significant.